# Typescript: Array may be undefined in array map function

Tags: typescript

I am receiving a Typescript error that says `'<array name>' is possibly undefined` when trying to map over an array in Typescript. Here is an example code that reproduces the error:

```js
type obj = {
    list?: string[]
};

function demonstration(ex: obj) {
    ex.list?.map((str) => {
        ex.list.findIndex(s => s === str); // error here
    })
}
```

I am aware that I can eliminate this error by adding an if check at the beginning of the map function, but I am more interested in understanding why this error occurs.

If the list's map function is executed at all, doesn't that imply that the list already exists? I suspect it may be a Typescript bug, but being new to Typescript, I'm not sure. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Of course it can be undefined - It's optional. Just put a return before the map. Something like `if !!!ex.list return`

Comment: @JoelHager That check exists already when the question mark is added to the end of `ex.list`. If you tried adding such a check explicitly, it will still show the error. What I'm curious about is why this error shows up despite the check.

Comment: The language cannot know that the array is still defined when the closure is actually executed by array map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of TypeScript, discussed in depth at [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  The type system doesn't currently have any way to notice or express when or even *whether* a callback is executed, so any [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) that has occurred to [closed-over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) variables is reset inside the scope of such callbacks.

There are various workarounds; the "standard" one is to copy the narrowed value to a new `const` variable in the same scope where it's been narrowed, and then use the new variable inside the closure.  That will work because the new variable is and will always be of the narrowed type:

```
function demonstration(ex: Obj) {
  if (ex.list) {
    const list = ex.list; // copy narrowed value to new variable
    list.map((str) => {
      list.findIndex(s => s === str); // okay
    })
  }
}
```

In the particular case of array functional methods like [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and access to the original array, you can augment your callback parameters to accept all three arguments, the third of which will be the original array:

```
function demonstration(ex: Obj) {
  ex.list?.map((str, _, list) => { // <-- third param will be the array
    list.findIndex(s => s === str); // okay
  })
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwFBSgGwJYDOwA-AFxREBOeAdgOYDaAuhgL4DcGGAZgK40BjYHgD2NKABMIAWzFUAhsLEAGABQQAHuXgIAlOixQ83KOo0A6fEX2Zs2AXOC5CT1JssvOd50XPT5YKqqVPrIAHwG3thWwObctBIAkjRSGsEoEQQoyKghXnasuoasbFx8gkriUrI0CpVm2og2hu4xxH4BQVQANFAA+r0xoRG2djFxCcmp6eEU2bnAlLrsUAD0q1AiANbyIMVFJVwYQA)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because TypeScript's type checker only seems to work for the highest level. If you introduce another variable that references `ex.list`, then TS can infer the type, though this does not work for the property of an object:

```
type obj = {
    list?: string[]
};

function working(ex: obj) {
    const e = ex.list
    if (e)
      e.map((str) => {
        e.findIndex(s => s === str); // no error, since type of e is array
      })
}

function alternativeWorking(ex: obj) {
  ex.list?.map((str) => {
    ex.list?.findIndex(s => s === str); // no error, explicit checking
  })
}

function notWorking(ex: obj) {
  ex.list?.map((str) => {
    ex.list.findIndex(s => s === str); // error here
  })
}
```

See also the [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKygXigbwFBW1ANgSwGdgB+ALimICd8A7AcwG0BdDAXwG4MMAzAV1oBjYPhi0oAdxhUA1nXoAKCAA8K8BAEp0WHILHEo0VCoB0BYjuz4eUJRss4IJgLYBDMAoXUtyAHzacQMMTHjoAEwBJWjCVLxR-QhRkVG8OKAB6dKhaGEMqKmkHbDZ7Nm5+IRExKFdcYAgqWlcRADcIAHVpOQYlVVhELUxsU3NSF3dPb3iAx2UzIjHQ6KiY5Ti-SiSU4CoNNMzs3IaCqh0S9nKBYVFxHOBO2XletQGZkYWScY8vHZ9-Idm82IIXCK1iiQ2EOSlF++yyx2kUAAFg0IGdSkA).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the callback of your `map` probably should return something, otherwise you just get an array of `undefined` elements.

Second, type-inference has its limits. If you are sure, that `ex.list` exists in the current content eventhough it's defined as `list?: string[]` (and you can in this case, because otherwise the callback would never have been called) you can simply use the [non null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) as follows

```
type obj = {
    list?: string[]
};

function demonstration(ex: obj) {
    ex.list?.map((str) => {
        return ex.list!.findIndex(s => s === str); // error here
    })
}
```